# How to convert code from pure JS to jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do an animation button with CSS3 that will change the burger to the cross when clicking. How to convert code from pure JS to jQuery?

```
var toggles = document.querySelectorAll(".cmn-toggle-switch");

for (var i = toggles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var toggle = toggles[i];
    toggleHandler(toggle);
};

function toggleHandler(toggle) {
    toggle.addEventListener( "click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        (this.classList.contains("active") === true) ? this.classList.remove("active") : this.classList.add("active");
    });
}
```

Comment: Why do you want something like that? Does your code have errors that you are insisting on using jQuery? Your code looks clean as it is.

Comment: I think `$(".cmn-toggle-switch").onClick(() => {  $(this).toggleClass("active") });` this will do

Comment: i think he wants less code

Comment: @AswinRamesh that won't work for several reasons ... there is no `onClick` in jQuery and no `this` in arrow functions

Comment: Oh I forgot... @charlietfl it should be like `$(".cmn-toggle-switch").click(function() { $(this).toggleClass("active"); });` right?

Answer (score 4):

There you go.

```
var toggles = $('.cmn-toggle-switch');

toggles.on('click', function(e){

      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass("active");

});
```

Comment: @AdamAzad i can not because of the level of reputation. I created an account a couple of days ago.